# Creating these dummy variables in R

Tags: r

Running a simulation of the St Petersberg game paradox, and I need to create these dummy variables for a certain number of outcomes. I have a tried appending in a for loop but cant seem to come out with the correct answer. Attached are the variables I need to create.
[image]

P(i) is an array in the form of {1/2^1,1/2^2,..,1/2^n}

Answer (score 1):

It's pretty easy to do this in `R`

```
# P= .5^k:r
P = .5^1:100
d1 = sum(P)
d2 = sum(P[-1]) # or just d1-.5
```

Or just by using the geometric sum formula :

[image]

```
d1 = (1-.5^100)
d2 = .5(1-.5^99)
```